# open jsp on jetty server

Tags: jsp, servlets, jetty

hi
i'm trying to build a website with jetty server. i want to open jsp page as the start page but i cant make it work from there.i tried this example . i put the war file in the webapps directory and i got the first jsp page (index.jsp). but when i tried to activate the form  i got this error message:

HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /GrettingServlet. Reason:

```
NOT_FOUND
```

this is the files:

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1255"
pageEncoding="windows-1255"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="GrettingServlet" method="POST">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" size="20"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" size="20">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

GrettingServlet.java :

```
package main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class GrettingServlet
 */

public class GrettingServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public GrettingServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName").toString();
    String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName").toString();

    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>Servlet GreetingServlet</title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<p>Welcome " + firstName + " " + lastName + "</p>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");

    out.close();
}


}
```

main.java:

```
package main;

import java.util.HashMap;
import org.mortbay.jetty.Connector;
import org.mortbay.jetty.Server;
import org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector;
import org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context;
import org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler;
import org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;
import org.mortbay.util.ajax.Continuation;

public class Main {
Server server;
Context root;
HelloServlet servlet;
HashMap <String, Continuation> hash;
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws Exception 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Main().start();
}

public void start()  throws Exception {
    hash = new HashMap<String, Continuation>();
    server = new Server(80);
            root = new WebAppContext(server,"C:/Users/sl300/Desktop/jetty/webapps/MyFirstServlet.war","/");
    server.start();
    server.join();

}

public void addContinuation(String str,Continuation cc){
    hash.put(str, cc);
}
    }
```

what is wrong? or how else i can open jsp?

Answer (score 0):

Would be helpful to see your web.xml file. Seems to be a problem with the servlet mapping. Another way would be to use a ServletHandler and add it to the server instance like

`GrettingServlet greetingServlet = new GrettingServlet();`

`ServletHandler servletHandler = new ServletHandler();`
`servletHandler.addServletWithMapping(greetingServlet, "/your/servlet/path");`
`server.addHandler(servletHandler);`

Comment: i tried that but then he didnt recognise the jsp file. i got this error when i tried to opent the index page from the browser: 
HTTP ERROR: 404

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    NOT_FOUND

Comment: Then you should show your web.xml file. You need to map your servlet like here: http://www.cs.uga.edu/~kochut/Teaching/x050/web-xml-explicit.html

Comment: it seem that i dont have web.xml file. where it should be?